# Rashi in Jyotisha - Sirodaya, Prushtodaya and Ubhayodaya

Tags: astrology, rashi

Shri [Bangalore Venkata Raman](http://www.journalofastrology.com/article.php?article_id=241) in his book [Hindu Predictive Astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_Venkata_Raman#Books) briefly mentions three types of Rashis - Sirodaya, Prushtodaya and Ubhayodaya.

What are these Rashis?

More importantly, where do these concepts find application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name implies::

### शिरोदय = शिर + उदय = Head + Rising:

ie. Those Rashis which rise through their head part while rising are Sheerodaya Rashi. Head and hind part of Rashi can be separated because Rashis are specific constellation having specific pattern of animals or object. ie. When they rise at east when head part is seen first while rising then they are called Sheerodaya Rashi.

Sheerodaya Rashi are: Mithun (Gemini), Simha (Leo), Kanya (Virgo), Tula (Libra), Vrishchik (Scorpio), Kumbha (Aquarius).

### पृष्ठोदय = पृष्ठ + उदय = Hind + Rising::

ie  Those Rashi which rise through their back part while rising are called Pristhodaya Rashi.

Pristhodaya Rashi are: Mesha (Aries), Vrish (Taurus), Karkat (Cancer), Dhanu (Saggitarus), Makara (Capricorn).

### उभयोदय = उभय + उदय = Both + Rising

ie. Those Rashis which rise from their both head and hind part are called Ubhayodaya Rashi. Pisces is the Ubhayodaya Rashi.

### Application:

The application of Sheersodaya, Pristhodaya and Ubhayodaya Rashi are useful in finding Rashi Bala (Power of Rashi) and Dasha Bala.

**Rashi Bala:** Ubahayodaya Rashi are powerful at both day and night.

Pristhodaya Rashi along with Gemini are powerful at night.

Sheershodaya Rashi: Powerful at day.

The above method to determine Rashi bala( potency of Rashi) is only one of the many methods to determine Rashi Bala.

**Dasha Bhuktani:**
During the period of planets ie. Dasha if the planet is situated at Seershodaya Rashi then it gives more fruits especially in first half of Dasha, if Pristhodaya then it gives more fruits especially in last half of Dasha, if Ubhayodaya gives fruit throught the Dasha.

But again this is only one of the aspect among many other aspects to determine Dasha Bhuktani Period.

Comment: I understood Dasha Bala. What does, say, Dhanu, being powerful at night mean, in Rashi Bala?

Comment: @Amit Saxena just like we have dasha of planets... we have also dasha of Rashi... but it isn't so popular... Rashi bala effects in that... also if Rashi is powerful then the planets residing there and its aspect also becomes powerful...simliarly it increase power of 12 houses as 1st house related to nature 2nd wealth 3rd brother 4th sukham 5th santan 6th shatru 7th dampatya 8th mrityu 9th dharma 10th karma 11th profit 12th loss... The potency of these houses also increases due to increase in Rashi Bala.... But as I have told this is just a minor aspect...

Answer (score 0):

Sheerodaya Rashi are: 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11

Pristhodaya Rashi are: 1, 2, 4, 9, 10.

Ubhayodaya Rashi is: 12

Best use of these rashis are in Medical Astrology.

Sheerodaya Rashi means Body part from Head to Navel
Pristhodaya Rashi means Navel to Feet
Ubhayodaya means full body

Check the power of impact on Rashi and point the limb related to it for the illness in the current or coming dasa.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).